# Bootstrap 3 nested row width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Let's assume we have this code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9" style="background-color: red;">
      <div style="background-color: purple;">
        Div inside the main row
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div style="background-color: blue;">
          Div in a nested row        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to make the nested row take the same width as the first div using Bootstrap ?

Thank you for your time

Comment: The bootstrap `.row` class has negative margin left and right 15px, thats why the `.row` element takes 30px wider of its parent element. Inside `.row` has `.col` child class and there has left and right 15px padding and the content has gap both sides. Now you use a nested `.row` (neg margin) which has content without `.col` child thats why the content takes nested row width.

Comment: You are right ! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the demo. the white gaps are container padding, border are container area and colored box is content.

- red border is just a sample wrapper (non bootstrap class).
- blue border is .container box
- yellow border is .row box
- black border is .col-* box

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.row {
  border: 2px solid orange;
}

[class*="col"] {
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div style="background-color: green;">
      Div inside container
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
        <div style="background-color: purple;">
          Div inside the main row and column
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div style="background-color: blue;">
            Div in a nested row
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: green;">
      Div inside container
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the demo it's pretty clear, but it's a little bit ugly to put a div with col-sm-12 inside a nested row just to have the right width. Don't you think ?

Comment: * If you strictly follow bootstrap lay-outing then there is no other way.

* If you use the content with custom class with left right 15px padding then you will not need col-sm-12 wrapper

* do not use .row class

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

As the second row has to be nested, you could surround:

```
<div style="background-color: blue;">
  Div in a nested row
</div>
```

With another div with the background-color set to white, or whatever the background-color of the page is.

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9" style="background-color: white;">
  <div style="background-color: blue;">
    Div in a nested row
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9" style="background-color: red;">
      <div style="background-color: purple;">
        Div inside the main row
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9" style="background-color: white;">
          <div style="background-color: blue;">
            Div in a nested row
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Old post:**

I would put them in seporate divs so that the div with the blue background is exactly like the one with the purple background, but it's parent has the `color: transparent;` or `color: white;` instead of `color: red;`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9" style="background-color: red;">
      <div style="background-color: purple;">
        Div inside the main row
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9" style="background-color: transparent;">
      <div style="background-color: blue;">
        Div in a nested row        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is just a sample. The code is more complicated and I need to have a nested row but I don't know how to make it take the same width as other divs

Comment: @Zak Ok I've revised my answer without taking the nested div out of the nest... What do you think?

Comment: @Zak Ok, could you create a JSFiddle or CodePen with the complex code so I can work with that?

Comment: Hey, your code seem working because of col-md-*, the JsFiddle screen is too small to test it. Try with col-xs-9 instead and you will see that it's not working. It's the same issue I have